# Mongoose find and pagination

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
// Routes
apiRouter.get('/information/common/:typeId/:page/:pageSize', function (req, res) {
    var _typeId = parseInt(req.params.typeId);
    var _page = parseInt(req.params.page);
    var _pageSize = parseInt(req.params.pageSize);

    newsModel.count({}, function (err, count) {
        if (err) { res.send(err); };
        newsModel.find({}).skip((_page-1)*_pageSize).limit(_pageSize).exec(function (err, datas) {
            if (err) { res.send(err); };
            res.json({
                code: 200,
                message: 'success',
                data: datas,
                count: count
            });
        });
    });
});

module.exports = apiRouter;
```

The code above, I want that can filter by `typeId`. `typeId` like `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`, when it equal `0`, get all the data from db, and when equal `1`, `2` or `3`, it get the type of it. :P

Answer (score 0):

Create an extra query object which you can populate the keys depending on the `typeId` value. For example:

```
// Routes
apiRouter.get('/information/common/:typeId/:page/:pageSize', function (req, res) {
    var _typeId = parseInt(req.params.typeId);
    var _page = parseInt(req.params.page);
    var _pageSize = parseInt(req.params.pageSize);
    var _query = {};

    if (!!_typeId) _query["typeId"] = _typeId;

    newsModel.count(_query, function (err, count) {
        if (err) { res.send(err); };
        newsModel.find(_query).skip((_page-1)*_pageSize).limit(_pageSize).exec(function (err, datas) {
            if (err) { res.send(err); };
            res.json({
                code: 200,
                message: 'success',
                data: datas,
                count: count
            });
        });
    });
});

module.exports = apiRouter;
```